# Error when compiling clang from trunk

Tags: c++, clang, address-sanitizer

I just got error when compiling clang. It seems it's a problem with address sanitizers compiled for iOS Simulator. I don't see any reason for it to link against libclang.dylib for x86_64. Has anybody seen it before? Or is there a way to turn it off?

```
DYLIB:   clang_darwin/ubsan_osx_dynamic/x86_64h:
/Users/bikineev/svn/clang/build/tools/clang/runtime/compiler-rt/clang_darwin/ubsan_osx_dynamic/x86_64h/libcompiler_rt.dylib
ld: warning: embedded dylibs/frameworks only run on iOS 8 or later ld:
building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX
file '/usr/local/lib//libc++.dylib' for architecture x86_64 clang:
error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```